# Disable mysql daily table optimization

Tags: mysql, debian, debian-based, turnkeylinux.org

I'm using Turnkey Linux LAMP and I need to disable the daily table optimization performed by mysql (my tables are InnoDB). The task starts automatically with user debian-sys-maint.
I cannot find where to disable it (or at least change it frequency).

I've checked my.cnf, init.d etc with no avail.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I doubt this is something that is part of MySQL itself. I've certainly never seen it.

I would say that it is much more likely to be running from cron. You should be able to find it in /etc/crontab, /etc/cron.d/ or /var/spool/cron/

Comment: Thanks in fact I found a "mysqloptimize" script in /etc/cron.daily. Seems like the culprit!